# how to customize calendar web control title

Tags: calendar, customization, asp.net-webcontrol

Here is my calendar. I want to be able to format the title marked with the red rectangle. How can I access that? What property should I change?

[image]

Comment: It would help if you specified what mark-up or code you use to render this control.

Answer (score 1):

The question does not specify mark-up nor code, so it is hard to give a good answer.

However, in general, formatting can to great extent be specified by css. I would recommend using the Firefox extension [Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/nl/firefox/addon/firebug/) to inspect the mark-up of the calendar. You can easily identify the element that corresponds to the title in the mark-up and specify custom css styles for it.

For instance, if your mark-up were:

```
<html>
<body>
    <div class="calendar">
        <h1>Events</h1>
        <h2><span>November 2012</span></h2>
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr><th>MON</th><th>TUE</th><th>WED</th><th>THU</th><th>FRI</th><th>SAT</th><th>SUM</th></tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr><td>29</td><td>30</td><td>31</td><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td></tr>
                <tr colspan="7"><td>...</td></th>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

you would add:

```
<style>
div.calendar h2 span /*selector for a span, in a h2, in a div that has class "calendar".*/
{
    border-color: red;
    border-width: 2px;
    border-style: solid;
}
</style>
```

to the html (or rather, create a dedicated css file) to draw a red rectangle around the month and year heading.